# pass string value inside a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, variables, logic

Can you guys help me?

Inside some php code i have a string variable $html as:

```
$html.='<img class="page_img current_thumb" src="'.site_url().'assets/admin/'.$data['edp_image'].'" alt="" title="" id="img_'.$i.'" onclick="return set_active('.$pub_id.','.$ed_id.','.$eddt.','.$i.','.$data['edp_page_num'].','.$tot_pages.');" id="img_'.$i.'" />';
```

Now the variables `$pub_id`,`$ed_id`,`$i`,`$tot_pages` and `$data['edp_page_num']` all contain integer values while the variable `$eddt` contains a date(like->2018-05-12)

When the variable `$html` is rendered, the onclick function looks like

```
return set_active(2,2,2018-04-15,1,1,2);
```

My question is how to pass the date value as '2018-04-15' and not as 2018-04-15.

Comment: In javascript you can use PHP variable values like: `var myVal = '<?php echo $myPhpVariable; ?>';`

Comment: Enclose it in escaped `'` like - `\''.$eddt.'\'`.

Comment: you need to use escape character like `'\'.$eddt.\''`

Comment: Thanks @Mr Blue, your answer did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Well there is **simple way** to do is:

```
'"'.$eddt.'"'
```

And another way to do is with an **enclose it in escaped** character :

```
'\'.$eddt.\''
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is to use `sprintf` which greatly simplifies your statement.

```
$num = 5;
$location = 'tree';

$format = 'There are %d monkeys in the "%s"';
echo sprintf($format, $num, $location);
```

Note the double quotes around `%s`.